# LibGit2Sharp - Access full Git Push Output

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I need to capture the full output from Git that results from a Push operation so that I can parse the error if needed.

Outside of LibGit2Sharp this could be done by redirecting the StandardError.

Is there a way to achieve this in the current library state? I looked through the classes and it seems that right now this is being obfuscated. Hopefully I missed something?

Comment: Output of `git push` through `libgit2`? I don't think that's gonna happen

Comment: To elaborate a little bit: I would expect the library to provide no output... applications would be in charge of generating it from interactions with the library.

Comment: 1. I am fine even if it isn't directly through LibGit2Sharp. But since the connection with Git is started and being managed via LibGit2Sharp I don't think there is a way to tap into listening to the underlying git process. 2. I don't think this is that crazy of an ask, and there have been many times where I have wished that I would have access to the output for different reasons.

Comment: A. You come back to examine your logs, and LibGit2Sharp says something like "Failed to push", or you don't see all the steps that Git went through and where specifically it is failing or succeeding. B. There are cases where you may want to retry an operation, or trigger an update of your source based on the exact reason why something fails in an automated way.

Comment: However, I do agree that in say LibGit2Sharp you may try to standardize this output, and maybe not just deliver the raw string, but I would take either at the moment haha.

Comment: libgit2 does not use git. It is a separate _from scratch_ implementation of git, afaik

Comment: If you want to get git output you will have to start a git process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibGit2Sharp is a wrapper around libgit2, which is a C library that reimplements Git functionality.  It's an independent library and doesn't use Git under the hood.

However, there are ways to use libgit2 to get information from the remote.  Since I was unable to quickly find a web page with documentation for LibGit2Sharp, I'll show you the libgit2 documentation, and let you figure out what that looks like in .NET.

When you push with libgit2, you can specify a set of callbacks that the library can provide when certain events occur.  This can be used to provide progress or other status information.  The [struct documentation](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_remote_callbacks) indicates a member called `sideband_progress`, which is the callback for textual output that the remote side sends.  In a normal `git push` invocation, that's the lines beginning with `remote:`.

Any time the remote side sends a complete line, that callback will be invoked and you'll get that output.  Do note that often the output contains a carriage return to overwrite the previous entry and that the callback may be invoked a significant number of times, which may impact how you wish to store and process the output.

Now, having said that, the ideal way to get your data is by using the error code from the library, since that's going to be the easiest and most reliable way to get data.  Parsing error messages is tricky; if you're talking to an arbitrary Git server, it's not guaranteed that it will use the same error messages as Git does, or even that any output it produces will be in English.  Sometimes, though, you can't avoid it, so if that's the case, you now know how to do it.

Comment: I will be reviewing this more in depth, but this seems like great info and what I need. Will update soon. Thanks for all the great info.

Comment: Also, I never realized libgit2 was stand alone which really helps my understanding, and gives direction for what is happening at a lower level. I downloaded the source repo, and have been looking for where the "Git" connection was made, but of course never found it. Good times.